# How to fix this problem of sync method in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have many to many relationships between User, Grade and Subject, the problem here is when I submit the data from the form to the update method in the controller, the sync method  `$user->subjects()->sync($request->subjects);` is adding every subject I selected to every grade I chose... what I want is when I chose a grade and a subject, that subject should be added under the grade which is selected for, not to every grade selected...I think the problem is in the  `$user->subjects()->sync($request->subjects);`, I'm not sure

For instance, in the picture below: I selected Grade 8 with Mathematics in the first block, but when I select Grade 9 with English in the second block and submit, the results came back like this... the Red encircled subjects shouldn't be checked. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
@foreach($classes as $key => $class)
                    <div class="card shadow mx-2 my-4">
                        <div class="card-header bg-light py-3">
                            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox"  id="{{$class->id}}" name="grade[]" value="{{ $class->id }}" 
                                    {{ ($user->grades->pluck('id')->contains($class->id)) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                                    <label class="custom-control-label pt-1" for="{{$class->id}}">{{$class->name}}</label>
                                </div>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">                      
                            @foreach($class->subjects as $key => $subject)
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror" id="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}" name="subjects[]" value="{{ $subject->id }}" 
                                {{ ($user->grades->pluck('id')->contains($class->id) && $user->subjects->pluck('id')->contains($subject->id)) ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$class->id}}{{$subject->id}}">{{$subject->name}}</label>
                            </div>   
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {  
       
        $user = User::where('id',$id)->first();
        .
    .
    .
    .
    .
           
        $user->save();
        
        $user->grades()->sync($request->grade);
        
        if($request->subjects){ 
            $user->subjects()->sync($request->subjects);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', $user->name . ' is updated Successfully');

    }
```

Relationships:

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;

use App\Events\UserRegistered;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    . 
    . 
    .
  

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Grade');
    }

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    }
}
```

Grade Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grade extends Model
{
   public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    }
    
   public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Subject Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subject extends Model
{
    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Grade');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

data $request

```
array:19 [▼
  "_token" => "r87fqYAVFkBIIYth9dvc6i9zxI73PkBztu3KdJ6f"
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "role" => "teacher"
  "last_name" => "Maya"
  "name" => "Vusumzi"
  "email" => "maya.vusumzi@gmail.com"
  "phone" => "0719087970"
  "gender" => "Male"
  "identity" => "8548976907564"
  "old_password" => null
  "new_password" => null
  "new_password_confirmation" => null
  "street" => "30 Sabalele street,"
  "suburb" => "Motherwell NU4B"
  "city" => "Port Elizabeth"
  "province" => "Eastern Cape"
  "code" => "6211"
  "grade" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  "subjects" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
]
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grade_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('grade_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('grade_id')->references('id')->on('grades')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['grade_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }


public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subject_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('subject_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['subject_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how the relationships are defined for user->grades and user->subjects? Can you aslo show $request->all() to show an example of the data?

Comment: @RobBiermann Relationships for user->grades and user->subjects are many to many...

Comment: I mean show us the exact definition, as it is related to the issue. Please update your question

Comment: As like in the migrations?

Comment: I think I spot the issue, give me a second to verify ;)

Comment: The issue is the part: `{{ ($user->grades->pluck('id')->contains($class->id) && $user->subjects->pluck('id')->contains($subject->id)) ? 'checked' : '' }}` You are basically cross-checking if both values are found. But that means if you check grade 10, you will also enable `english` and `mathematics` too. With `enable` i mean that you check it in the panel.

Comment: Yes.. That is the problem, That is where I'm stuck ;) ... how do I fix that?... Thank you for your time man

Comment: To be honest, the solution is not that easy as there is a flaw in your database design.(and the design is based on your whole app) You are currently storing both grades and subjects in separate pivot tables. I think you should combine these into one table.  That way you should be able to query if a user has a grade and a subject in the table. If so, check it, if not, uncheck it.

Comment: Ok I see...Thanks